# DialogFlow - Modified 'Bike Shop' Sample Won't Work

Tags: parameters, split, properties, dialogflow-es

I'm having some serious difficulties getting a modified version (or the original version, for that matter) of this Bike Shop example to work.

I'm attempting to duplicate the basic functionality, but add fields for Name, Phone Number, Email, etc. into the calendar event.

Maybe it's because this is my first soiree with Node.js, but this is proving to be less enjoyable than bathing in hot cement.

I'll quickly summarize the main issues I've been having:

**Getting events to populate in Calendar**

So I've gotten just about everything sorted out thanks to @Prisoner. My main issue was that my contexts were capitalized, therefore not recognized. Converting most of the intents to top-level helped as well. Now I can consistently get the fulfillment responses to fill in and give me my first confirmation message, but I always get my second 'error' response and no event is made in the calendar.

**Not showing on calendar**
How do I update the googleapis library? Just change the ^27 to ^30 in the package.json?

**Contexts**
Isn't `.getContext()` deprecated? That's what it says here (https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts/contexts-fulfillment) and that's what the error said when I tried it yesterday.

**Entities with a hyphen**
I changed the name (I didn't know the name wasn't just a label), but for future reference and clarity, is it `.parameters`, `.properties`, or `.params`?

**And just for reference, here's my Intent flow:**
Scheduleappointment  >

FirstLast (gets first and last name, assigns to system entities) >

ServiceNeeded (gets service needed, assigns to developer entity) >

Date Time MeetingPlace Email PhoneN (gets date, time, phone number & email: assigns to system entities; gets location: assigns to developer entity)

My index.js:

```
/**
 * Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

// Enter your calendar ID and service account JSON below.
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/bike-shop/blob/master/README.md#calendar-setup
const calendarId = 'm6t2gekgnv2qro9ln8genh10o8@group.calendar.google.com'; // Example: 6ujc6j6rgfk02cp02vg6h38cs0@group.calendar.google.com
const serviceAccount = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "appsoft-lead-net",
  "private_key_id": "863c577bd9249f09cbce540cf082fb7c1f7349ac",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "id-appsoft-chatbot-v1-calendar@appsoft-lead-net.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "113420745582984409565",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/id-appsoft-chatbot-v1-calendar%40appsoft-lead-net.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}; // The JSON object looks like: { "type": "service_account", ... }

// Set up Google Calendar service account credentials
const serviceAccountAuth = new google.auth.JWT({
  email: serviceAccount.client_email,
  key: serviceAccount.private_key,
  scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
});

const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // It enables lib debugging statements

const timeZone = 'America/New_York';  // Change it to your time zone

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  // This function receives the date and time values from the context 'MakeAppointment-followup'
  // and calls the createCalendarEvent() function to mark the specified time slot on Google Calendar.
  function makeAppointment (agent) {
    // Get the contexts
    const contextF = agent.context.get('firstlast');
    const contextS = agent.context.get('serviceneeded');
    const contextD = agent.context.get('datetimemeetingplaceemailphonen-followup');
    // This variable needs to hold an instance of Date object that specifies the start time of the appointment.
    const dateTimeStart = convertTimestampToDate(contextD.parameters.date, contextD.parameters.time);
    // This variable holds the end time of the appointment, which is calculated by adding an hour to the start time.
    const dateTimeEnd = addHours(dateTimeStart, 1);
    // Convert the Date object into human-readable strings.
    const appointmentTimeString = getLocaleTimeString(dateTimeStart);
    const appointmentDateString = getLocaleDateString(dateTimeStart);
// set properties to variables
const appointmentLocationString = contextD.parameters.meetingPlace;
const appointmentEmail = contextD.parameters.email;
const appointmentService = contextS.parameters.ServiceNeeded;
const appointmentFullName = contextF.parameters.givenName + " " + contextF.parameters.lastName;
const appointmentFirstName = contextF.parameters.givenName;
const appointmentPhoneString = contextD.parameters.phoneNumber;
    // Delete the context 'MakeAppointment-followup'; this is the final step of the path.
    agent.context.delete('datetimemeetingplaceemailphonen-followup');
    // The createCalendarEvent() function checks the availability of the time slot and marks the time slot on Google Calendar if the slot is available.
    return createCalendarEvent(agent, dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointmentFullName, appointmentPhoneString, appointmentLocationString, appointmentEmail, appointmentService).then(() => {
        agent.context.delete('serviceneeded');
        agent.context.delete('firstlast');
        agent.context.delete('schedule');
      agent.add(`Got it! I have your appointment scheduled on ${appointmentDateString} at ${appointmentTimeString}—we'll contact you shortly to confirm the deets! See you soon, ${appointmentFirstName}. Good-bye!`);
    }).catch(() => {
      agent.add(`Sorry, ${appointmentFirstName}, something went wrong—I couldn't book ${appointmentDateString} at ${appointmentTimeString}. Try trying again! If that doesn't work, let us know—Mitch probably just messed up something...`);
    });
  }

  // This function receives the date and time values from the context 'MakeAppointment-followup'
  // and calls the checkCalendarAvailablity() function to check the availability of the time slot on Google Calendar.
  function checkAppointment (agent) {
      // Get the contexts
      const contextF = agent.context.get('firstlast');
      const contextS = agent.context.get('serviceneeded');
    // This variable needs to hold an instance of Date object that specifies the start time of the appointment.
    const dateTimeStart = convertTimestampToDate(agent.parameters.date, agent.parameters.time);
    // This variable holds the end time of the appointment, which is calculated by adding an hour to the start time.
    const dateTimeEnd = addHours(dateTimeStart, 1);
    // Convert the Date object into human-readable strings.
    const appointmentTimeString = getLocaleTimeString(dateTimeStart);
    const appointmentDateString = getLocaleDateString(dateTimeStart);
    // set properties into variables
    const appointmentLocationString = agent.parameters.meetingPlace;
    const appointmentEmail = agent.parameters.email;
    const appointmentService = contextS.parameters.ServiceNeeded;
    const appointmentFullName = contextF.parameters.givenName + " " + contextF.parameters.lastName;
    const appointmentFirstName = contextF.parameters.givenName;
    const appointmentPhoneString = agent.parameters.phoneNumber;
    // The checkCalendarAvailablity() function checks the availability of the time slot.
    return checkCalendarAvailablity(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd).then(() => {
        // The time slot is available.
       // The function returns a response that asks for the confirmation of the date and time.
       agent.add(`Okay, ${appointmentFullName}, so you've said that you'd like your appointment on ${appointmentDateString} at ${appointmentTimeString}. We'll call ${appointmentPhoneString} and/or email ${appointmentEmail} to confirm this appointment ${appointmentLocationString} about ${appointmentService}. Did I get that right?`);
     }).catch(() => {
       // The time slot is not available.
       agent.add(`Sorry, ${appointmentFirstName}, we're booked up on ${appointmentDateString} at ${appointmentTimeString}. Huge bummer, I know =/ But is there another time you'd like to schedule your appointment?`);
       // Delete the context 'MakeAppointment-followup' to return the flow of conversation to the beginning.
       agent.context.delete('datetimemeetingplaceemailphonen-followup');
   });
  }
  // Mapping of the functions to the agent's intents.
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Date Time MeetingPlace Email PhoneN', checkAppointment);
  intentMap.set('Date Time MeetingPlace Email PhoneN - yes', makeAppointment);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

// This function checks for the availability of the time slot, which starts at 'dateTimeStart' and ends at 'dateTimeEnd'.
// 'dateTimeStart' and 'dateTimeEnd' are instances of a Date object.
function checkCalendarAvailablity (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calendar.events.list({
      auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
      calendarId: calendarId,
      timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
      timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
    }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
      // Check if there is an event already on the Calendar
      if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
      }else {
        resolve(calendarResponse);
      }
    });
  });
}

// This function marks the time slot on Google Calendar. The time slot on the calendar starts at 'dateTimeStart' and ends at 'dateTimeEnd'.
// 'dateTimeStart' and 'dateTimeEnd' are instances of a Date object.
function createCalendarEvent (agent, dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointmentFullName, appointmentPhoneString, appointmentLocationString, appointmentEmail, appointmentService) {

// assign values to variables
    appointmentPhoneString = agent.parameters.phoneNumber;
    appointmentLocationString = agent.parameters.meetingPlace;
    appointmentEmail = agent.parameters.email;
    appointmentService = agent.parameters.ServiceNeeded;
    appointmentFullName = agent.parameters.givenName + " " + agent.parameters.lastName;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calendar.events.list({
      auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
      calendarId: calendarId,
      timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
      timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
    }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
      // Check if there is an event already on the Calendar
      if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
      } else {
        // Create event for the requested time period
        calendar.events.insert({ auth: serviceAccountAuth,
          calendarId: calendarId,
          resource: {
           summary: 'Appsoft Appointment',
           start: {
             dateTime: dateTimeStart
           },
           end: {
             dateTime: dateTimeEnd
           },
           attendees:[ {
             displayName: appointmentFullName,
             email: appointmentEmail,
           }],
           location: appointmentLocationString,
           description: 'Phone Number: ' + appointmentPhoneString + '; Service Needed: ' + appointmentService}
        }, (err, event) => {
          err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
        }
        );
      }
    });
  });
}

// A helper function that receives Dialogflow's 'date' and 'time' parameters and creates a Date instance.
function convertTimestampToDate(date, time){
  // Parse the date, time, and time zone offset values from the input parameters and create a new Date object
  return new Date(Date.parse(date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] + '-' + time.split('T')[1].split('-')[1]));
}

// A helper function that adds the integer value of 'hoursToAdd' to the Date instance 'dateObj' and returns a new Data instance.
function addHours(dateObj, hoursToAdd){
  return new Date(new Date(dateObj).setHours(dateObj.getHours() + hoursToAdd));
}

// A helper function that converts the Date instance 'dateObj' into a string that represents this time in English.
function getLocaleTimeString(dateObj){
  return dateObj.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true, timeZone: timeZone });
}

// A helper function that converts the Date instance 'dateObj' into a string that represents this date in English.
function getLocaleDateString(dateObj){
  return dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone });
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "DialogflowFirebaseWebhook",
  "description": "Firebase Webhook dependencies for a Dialogflow agent.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "semistandard --fix \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0",
    "actions-on-google": "2.2.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.6.1"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

{Fixed Edit: Finally got it working, turns out context names need to be entirely lowercase to be recognized. Also , I was declaring the variables in the `createCalendarEvent` improperly and for no reason. }

Answer (score 1):

Lots of issues, so lets's see what we can untangle.

**Cannot read property 'split'**

Line 192 is

```
return new Date(Date.parse(date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] + '-' + time.split('T')[1].split('-')[1]));
```

which has a lot of calls to `split()`, so its not clear exactly which one is causing the problem, but this is happening because either `date` or `time` (or both) aren't defined.

The `convertTimestampToDate()` function, which contains this line, is called from two different places. Your `makeAppointment()` and `checkAppointment()` functions, which both seem to have the same line

```
    const dateTimeStart = convertTimestampToDate(agent.parameters.date, agent.parameters.time);
```

You don't show the `Schedule appointment - Date Time meetingPlace` or `Schedule appointment - Date Time meetingPlace - yes` Intent configurations themselves, but it sounds like one of them doesn't actually have a `date` or `time` parameter.

**Response from fulfillment**

You're a bit vague on which responses aren't being generated, but for the two Intents that have a handler, the responses seem to be setup correctly.

The ones from the UI would be used under any of the following circumstances:

- Fulfillment is not enabled for that Intent.
- Fulfillment does not explicitly add a reply.

There *is* a limit of 640 characters per message, but I don't think you're hitting that limit with your replies, tho I suppose it might be possible in some cases.

**Dynamic parameters are undefined**

I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamic", but This sounds like the same issue as `date` and `time` being undefined. Again, I'd check to make sure those parameters are being sent in the Intents you think they are.

From the Intent "flow" (which I'll discuss below), it sounds like you're expecting the parameters to keep being populated from Intent to Intent. In general, the parameters are what was provided from the *current* Intent.

If you have an Output Context set, then the parameters may also be set in the Context, which will carry forward to future Intents. So you may want to be getting them from the Context, rather than from the parameters.

*Update based on sid's comments below*: If you **do** want past parameters in current Intent parameters, you need to explicitly set the value in your Intent from the context with something like `#output-context.param` in the Intent parameter section.

**Not showing on calendar**

You're using a fairly old version of the [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) library, which may or may not be the problem. Newer ones, however, support Promises natively, which would certainly make your code somewhat easier to work with.

I'm not positive this is it, but you're specifying a property called `resource` which contains the events resource (as per the [specification](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)) and which should be in the body of the request. I don't know if this changed from the library you're using, but in the [current library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#specifying-request-body), this field should be called `requestBody`.

**Contexts**

The best way to handle contexts is to use direct accessor methods such as [`agent.getContext()`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client#webhookclientgetcontextcontextname_%E2%87%92_object), [`agent.setContext()`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client#webhookclientsetcontextcontext_%E2%87%92_webhookclient), and [`agent.clearContext()`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client#webhookclientclearcontextcontext_%E2%87%92_webhookclient).

You may have seen some older documentation for Actions on Google which talk about `conv.contexts`, which don't apply in this case.

**Entities with a hyphen**

The easiest way is to change the name of the parameter in the Intent UI to something without a hyphen. You can call them whatever you want - you don't have to name them after the entity type.

If you do want to keep the hyphen, you index them against the `agent.properties` object (which appears to be how you did so). So

```
agent.properties['what-ever']
```

**Intent Flow**

You don't show the Intent configuration, but it sounds like you have these questions as a series of Followup Intents.

This... is not always a good idea. Conversations aren't always linear, and users may try to go backwards (or forwards) in a conversation, which Followup Intents don't handle well.

A better solution is to have most of these Intents as top level, all of which use fulfillment. The Intents are responsible for delivering parmeters to the fulfillment, which stores them, and then determines which values are still missing and asks for one. If you feel you need to narrow what you expect from the user, you can look into using Contexts, but this isn't as necessary as you might think. (See [Thinking for Voice: Design Conversations not Logic](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/thinking-for-voice-design-conversations-not-logic-7c60869451f1) for some discussion about this.)

Comment: one more problem could be, setting the output-context but not mentioning the **default value** of the parameter in next intent as `#output-context.parameter_name`, if we dont set this then parameter is set to Null again.

Comment: An excellent point. I've updated that part of the answer to incorporate your comment.

Comment: @Prisoner Edited question to include response to your comment